# How to plot a map from gadm in shiny r?

Tags: r, shiny, visualization, raster

im new to shiny and currrently m trying to plot the map of Pakistan in my shiny app. The code that im currently using works perfectly on the console, but im not quite sure as to how to implement it in my shiny app. [![Console Output][1]][1]THE code:

```
library(maptools)
library(raster)
    adm <- raster::getData('GADM', country='PAK', level=2),
          mar<-(adm),
          plot(mar, bg="dodgerblue", axes=T),
          ##Plot downloaded data
          plot(mar, lwd=10, border="skyblue", add=T),
          plot(mar,col="green4", add=T),
          grid(),
          box(),
          invisible(text(getSpPPolygonsLabptSlots(mar), labels=as.character(mar$NAME_2), cex=1.1, col="white", font=2)),
          mtext(side=3, line=1, "Pakistan", cex=2),
          mtext(side=1, "Longitude", line=2.5, cex=1.1),
          mtext(side=2, "Latitude", line=2.5, cex=1.1)
```

#

This is what im currently doing in the Shiny app:

```
**ui.r**

    shinyUI(
      navbarPage(
        inverse = TRUE,
        title = "Campaign Launch Demo",
    tabPanel("Daily Insights",
    sidebarLayout(
          sidebarPanel( )


     mainPanel(
          fluid = TRUE,
        uiOutput('map2')
        )
        )
        )
        )
        )

and this the code for the server script:
     **server.R**
       shinyServer(function(input, output, session){
         output$map2 <- 
            print(
              ## Download data from gadm.org 
              adm <- raster::getData('GADM', country='PAK', level=2),
              mar<-(adm),
              plot(mar, bg="dodgerblue", axes=T),
              ##Plot downloaded data
              plot(mar, lwd=10, border="skyblue", add=T),
              plot(mar,col="green4", add=T),
              grid(),
              box(),
              invisible(text(getSpPPolygonsLabptSlots(mar), labels=as.character(mar$NAME_2), cex=1.1, col="white", font=2)),
              mtext(side=3, line=1, "Pakistan", cex=2),
              mtext(side=1, "Longitude", line=2.5, cex=1.1),
              mtext(side=2, "Latitude", line=2.5, cex=1.1)
        )   }



  [1]:
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ihfvM.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `ui.R` use `plotOutput()` instead of `uiOutput()`.

```
shinyUI(
  navbarPage(
  inverse = TRUE,
  title = "Campaign Launch Demo",
  tabPanel("Daily Insights",
     sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(),
        mainPanel(fluid = TRUE, plotOutput('map2'))
     ))))
```

In `server.R` use `renderPlot()` function and get rid of the commas at the end of every line.

```
library(maptools)
library(raster)

shinyServer(function(input, output, session){
  output$map2 <- renderPlot({
    ## Download data from gadm.org 
    adm <- raster::getData('GADM', country='PAK', level=2)
    mar<-(adm)
    plot(mar, bg="dodgerblue", axes=T)
    ##Plot downloaded data
    plot(mar, lwd=10, border="skyblue", add=T)
    plot(mar,col="green4", add=T)
    grid()
    box()
    invisible(text(getSpPPolygonsLabptSlots(mar), labels=as.character(mar$NAME_2), cex=1.1, col="white", font=2))
    mtext(side=3, line=1, "Pakistan", cex=2)
    mtext(side=1, "Longitude", line=2.5, cex=1.1)
    mtext(side=2, "Latitude", line=2.5, cex=1.1)
  })
})
```